# BeginGetRequestStream takes a long time for callback in WPF

Tags: asp.net, wpf, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

I have an application that is a load tester, and uses async web api to send lots of traffic to a test server.  The application has 2 GUI incarnations: one is a web app which is controlled via standard .aspx forms.  Another is a WPF forms application.  The http code however is the same in both cases so I'm confused as to why the performance difference.

In the WPF application there is about 30 seconds before GetRequestStreamCallback is called by the CLR.  In the web application it is more like 40ms.  I suspect this has something to do with the threading model in the 2 applications (there are lots of threads not shown here).  Since the GetRequestStreamCallback is a callback I have no influence over the priority it is called.

Any insight is appreciated,
Aaron

```
public class PendingRequestWrapper
{
    public HttpWebRequest request;
    PendingRequestWraqpper(HttpWebRequest req) {request = req;}
}

public class Poster
{
    public static void SendPost(string url) {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        // more header setup ...

        PendingRequestWrapper = new PendingRequestWrapper(request);
        wrap.request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), wrap);        
}
private static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    PendingRequestWrapper wrap = asynchronousResult.AsyncState as PendingRequestWrapper;

    try {
        // End the operation
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeln("Received req stream for " + wrap.request.RequestUri.ToString());
        Stream postStream = wrap.request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
    } catch(Exception e) 
    {
        // ...
    }
    // Use the stream
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason WPF has slower asp.net web performance than an IIS web application by default is that the default connection limit per host is 2.  Whereas in IIS application it defaults to 32k.  The fix is to go:

```
        ServicePoint myPoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri("http://example.com"));

        // WPF application needs this!
        myPoint.ConnectionLimit = 10000;
```

This is probably irrelevant to all applications except for load-testing-types that open many connections to the same host.